# How to call multiple API and render the response of all those API in a template in django

Tags: python, django, api, templates, post

I tried rendering the response of multiple API in a single template but since once one view can we passed in the path, i am unable to think of what i can do

I tried keeping the two functions to call the API inside a class but i got GET 405 error

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OtpV.png)

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flm0n.png)

Comment: you can pass different API reponse to template by context .Just hit all API in view and add each response in context dictionary like {'response1':response1,'response2':response2} and pass on to template.

Comment: can you share your code with us?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you guys, your suggestion worked

Answer (score 0):

First of all cant say anything without seeing the code but I think you can create a dictionary and pass it as context in response. Save the multiple api and pass it into dictionary

```
mydict = {
   "api1":api_data,
   "api2":api_data,
}
```

pass this as context in response